# What's the possible usage of ".gitignore~" in a gitignore file?

Tags: gitignore

I can't understand it's usage because tilde is not a metacharacter in Regular expression.

I saw it here:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest/blob/master/.gitignore

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest/commit/a086df26fd7e6b54b369d4fa0b45522c9bc3a570#diff-a084b794bc0759e7a6b77810e01874f2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some editors like emacs make [backup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names) that end in a tilde, so this rule would ignore any backups made while editing .gitignore itself